# Specific approach to integral

Tags: calculus

Problem: Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin^3{x}}{x \cdot e^x} dx=\dfrac{A\pi}{B}-\dfrac{\tan^{-1} (C)}{D},$$
Attempt through Differentiation under the Integral Sign:

Using $\sin^3x=\frac{3\sin x-\sin 3x}{4}$, rewrite as
$$ \frac{3}{4}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}\sin x}{x}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}\sin 3x}{x}\,dx $$

$$ I(b)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}\sin bx}{x}\,dx\qquad,\qquad\mbox{where}\,\,b>0 $$
$$ \begin{align} I'(b)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos bx\,dx\\ \end{align} $$

How to proceed, please?

Comment: What are $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: @avid19: it looks like a problem from Brilliant. One is usually supposed to find $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** You may just write, for $b \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\cos bx\: dx=\Re\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(1+ib)x} dx=\Re\left. \frac{e^{-(1+ib)x}}{-(1+ib)}\right|_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{1+b^2}.
$$
Alternatively, integrating by parts twice:
$$
\begin{align}
I(b)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\cos bx\: dx&=\left.-e^{-x}\cos bx\right|_0^{\infty}-b\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin bx\: dx\\\\
&=1-b\times\left(\left.-e^{-x}\sin bx\right|_0^{\infty}+b\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\cos bx\: dx\right)\\\\
&=1-b^2I(b)
\end{align}
$$ giving $\displaystyle (1+b^2)I(b)=1$ and
$$
I(b)=\frac{1}{1+b^2}.
$$

Comment: @BetterWorld By parts? yes. I will edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @BetterWorld Done. Hoping it is OK for you now :)

Comment: @BetterWorld: Neither $\sin$ nor $\cos$ have a limit towards $\infty$. Fortunately, at least they are bounded. Also fortunately, $\Bbb e ^{-x}$ tends to $0$ when $x \to \infty$. So, their product will also tend to $0$. Keep in mind this useful general fact: the product of a bounded function and a function that tends to $0$ will also tend to $0$.

Comment: @BetterWorld You may write $\left|-e^{-x}\cos bx\right|\leq |e^{-x}| \times  |\cos (bx)|\leq |e^{-x}| \to 0$ and $\left|-e^{-x}\sin bx\right|\leq |e^{-x}| \times  |\sin (bx)|\leq |e^{-x}| \to 0$, as $x\to +\infty$, since $|\cos (bx)|\leq 1$ and  $|\sin (bx)|\leq1$. Thanks!

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Typing problem: too few bars in the moduli!

Comment: @BetterWorld You may recall that you always have $|a \times b|\leq |a|\times |b|$, here take $a=e^{-x}$ and $b=\cos (bx)$, and I hope you know that  $e^{-x}>0$ thus $|e^{-x}|=e^{-x}$ and I hope you know that $e^{-x}=\frac1{e^x} \to \frac1{e^{\infty}}=0$ as $x \to +\infty$. Tell me.

Answer (score 2):

We may use:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x\,e^{x}}\,dx = \int_{1}^{+\infty}(\mathcal{L}\,f)(t)\,dt \tag{1}$$
so we just need to find the Laplace transform of $\sin^3(x)$.

Pretty easy task through the triplication formulas, since $\mathcal{L}(\sin x)=\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ implies:
$$ \mathcal{L}(\sin^3 x) = \frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{t^2+1}-\frac{1}{t^2+9}\right)=\frac{6}{(1+t^2)(9+t^2)}\tag{2}$$
then:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^3 x}{x\,e^{x}}\,dx = \frac{3\pi}{16}-\frac{3}{4}\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t^2+9}=\color{red}{\frac{3\pi}{16}-\frac{\arctan 3}{4}}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: @BetterWorld: I hope you just need the definition. With a little digging into Wikipedia, it won't be difficult to prove $(1)$. The Laplace transform of a function $f(x)$ is defined as: $$(\mathcal{L} f)(s)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x)\, e^{-sx}\,dx.$$